# Is it possible to redirect a url(not in my domain) to another using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I was using a third party online store and had a particular url assigned for the store.
Now I have changed the third party and have a new store url.
But, some people whose browser has cached the old url still use it.

So, is there a way to redirect the old url to the new one?
Both are store urls assigned to me but they are not in my domain.

Or, is there a way to forcibly empty the browser cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to redirect a third party url without having access to their server.

Answer (score 0):

In htacces file write

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new_url
```

I have no knowledge of htacces but still iam damn sure that it is correct and will work for you.

Comment: don't forget to aceppt this answer:-)

Comment: I have to redirect from a particular third party url to another 3rd party url. I dont have access to their servers. I think the above rule redirect any request to the new url

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the redirection related code to the server root where the old URL is pointing.

if your old url http://xyz.com points to some server with IP w.x.y.z then you need to add the .htaccess redirection rule on that particular server.

So my question is, do you have access to that old server?

Comment: Then it seems like you will have to request to the person who has access, else it won't be possible